# How does bulkDelete work?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, bulk, discord.js

I tried using `bulkDelete` to make my bot delete its message but I get this error:

```
(node:5724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Bad Request
(node:5724) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('I am ready!');
});

//var cleanarr=[];

bot.on("message", message =>{
    if (message.author.bot) return;
var cleanarr=[];
        let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
command = command.slice(config.prefix.length);

        let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
if (message.content == 'lol'){
    message.channel.sendMessage('LUL');
    cleanarr.unshift(`${message.channel.lastMessageID}`);
    }
if (command == "clean") {
    message.channel.sendMessage('Cleaning...');
    message.channel.bulkDelete(cleanarr);
    var cleanarr = [];
```

What does the bulkDelete need? Is it the message id or something else?

I have no idea if I doing this right (obviously I am not) since I started coding with zero knowledge of javascript or anything related.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to delete `x` messages from a channel is to provide an integer from `2 - 100` as parameters to the [`<TextChannel>.bulkDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) method.

Example:

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(100).then(() => {
  message.channel.send("Deleted 100 messages.").then(msg => msg.delete(3000));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The discord bulk delete endpoint requires the array of messages you would like deleted. Small note here as of yesterday the bulk delete endpoint will not remove messages older than 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more updated one;

```
    }else if (command === 'purge') {
    const amount = parseInt(args[0]);

    if (isNaN(amount)) {
        return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');
    }

    if (isNaN(amount)) {
    return message.reply('You have enterd a invalid amount. Try ``purge 5``');
} else if (amount < 2 || amount > 100) {
    return message.reply('you need to input a number between 2 and 100.');
}
message.channel.bulkDelete(amount);
message.channel.send(amount + ' ' +'messages deleted');

    }
});
```