# BulkDelete Discord.js (How to add interger parsing)

Tags: discord.js

How to bulkDelete in discord.js. Please give me a program  for it...

```
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'Ping':
            message.channel.send('Pong!');
            break;
        case 'clear':
            if (!args[1]) return message.reply('Error please mention second arg');
            message.delete.bulkDelete(args[1]);
            break;
    }
})
```

I've tried the above code and found " TypeError: message.delete.bulkDelete is not a function "

as error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? It may be a duplicate. [How does bulkDelete work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574971/how-does-bulkdelete-work)

Comment: I got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, you replace:

```
message.delete.bulkDelete(args[1]);
```

with:

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(Number.parseInt(args[1]));
```

Comment: If I use some integer instead of args[1] its working fine but if I use args[1] error is thrown

Comment: I tried as u said it works if its an integer not args[1]

Comment: @toxicbiohazard Okay, then replace `args[1]` with `Number.parseInt(args[1])`